# multiple images resize with jquery (client-side)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a working upload script/form into my images but i cant figure how to do that for multiple images in the code below..

The code works fine for one image but i couldnt figure for multiple images work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.imageUploadResizer = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            max_width: 1000,
            max_height: 1000,
            quality: 1,
            do_not_resize: [],
        }, options );

        this.filter('input[type="files"]').each(function () {
            this.onchange = function() {
                const that = this; 
                const originalFile = this.files[0];
               
                if (!originalFile || !originalFile.type.startsWith('image')) {
                    return;
                }

                // Don't resize if doNotResize is set
                if (settings.do_not_resize.includes('*') || settings.do_not_resize.includes( originalFile.type.split('/')[1])) {
                    return;
                }

                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

                    img.src = e.target.result
                    img.onload = function () {
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                        if (img.width < settings.max_width && img.height < settings.max_height) {
                            // Resize not required
                            return;
                        }

                        const ratio = Math.min(settings.max_width / img.width, settings.max_height / img.height);
                        const width = Math.round(img.width * ratio);
                        const height = Math.round(img.height * ratio);

                        canvas.width = width;
                        canvas.height = height;

                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                            var resizedFile = new File([blob], 'resized_'+originalFile.name, originalFile);

                            var dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
                            dataTransfer.items.add(resizedFile);

                            // temporary remove event listener, change and restore
                            var currentOnChange = that.onchange;

                            that.onchange = null;
                            that.files = dataTransfer.files;
                            that.onchange = currentOnChange;

                        }, 'image/jpeg', settings.quality);
                    }
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(originalFile);
            }
        });
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

is there a way to change this code to multiple images that returns ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.imageUploadResizer = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            max_width: 1000,
            max_height: 1000,
            quality: 1,
            do_not_resize: [],            
        }, options);

        this.filter('input[type="file"]').each(function () {
            this.onchange = function () {
                var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
                var dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
                for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
                    var that = this; // input node
                    var originalFile = this.files[i];

                    if (!originalFile || !originalFile.type.startsWith('image')) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Don't resize if doNotResize is set
                    if (settings.do_not_resize.includes('*') || settings.do_not_resize.includes(originalFile.type.split('/')[1])) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

                        img.src = e.target.result
                        img.onload = function () {
                            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                            if (img.width < settings.max_width && img.height < settings.max_height) {
                                // Resize not required
                                return;
                            }

                            const ratio = Math.min(settings.max_width / img.width, settings.max_height / img.height);
                            const width = Math.round(img.width * ratio);
                            const height = Math.round(img.height * ratio);

                            canvas.width = width;
                            canvas.height = height;

                            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                            canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                                var resizedFile = new File([blob], 'resized_' + originalFile.name, originalFile);

                                
                                dataTransfer.items.add(resizedFile);

                                // temporary remove event listener, change and restore
                                var currentOnChange = that.onchange;

                                that.onchange = null;
                                that.files = dataTransfer.files;
                                that.onchange = currentOnChange;

                            }, 'image/jpeg', settings.quality);
                        }
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(originalFile);
                }
            }
        });

        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are problematic. Could you please explain what you changed and why?